# Search con query personalizada y 2 parametros Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con lo siguiente en Java Spring Boot:

Como puedo hacer un search (GET) de la siguiente manera:

@GetMapping("searchDocument/{columna}/{valor}")

Por ejemplo que busque de la Base de Datos "Documentos" la columna y el valor que envie mediante el endpoint y que me devuelva el documento encontrado que coincida , de lo contrario que me envie un mensaje de que no se encontraron coincidencias, en el fondo es, como puedo manejar 2 parametros dinamicos? Porque existe el metodo findById(), pero no necesariamente quiero buscar por id, si no que puede ser por nombre , fecha, codigo.

Por ejemplo @GetMapping("searchDocument/nro_documento/123") @GetMapping("searchDocument/fecha_documento/2022-09-08") @GetMapping("searchDocument/nombre_documento/documento1")

De momento mi código se encuentra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de compilar el programa me arroja el siguiente error:

"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IDocumentoRepository' defined in pe.engageone.vault.ApiVault.documentos.repository.IDocumentoRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List pe.engageone.vault.ApiVault.documentos.repository.IDocumentoRepository.findDocumentByColumnaAndValor(java.lang.String,java.lang.String); Reason: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List pe.engageone.vault.ApiVault.documentos.repository.IDocumentoRepository.findDocumentByColumnaAndValor(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) but parameter 'Optional[Valor]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT * FROM Documentos WHERE :Columna LIKE :%Valor%'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List pe.engageone.vault.ApiVault.documentos.repository.IDocumentoRepository.findDocumentByColumnaAndValor(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) but parameter 'Optional[Valor]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT * FROM Documentos WHERE :Columna LIKE :%Valor%'!"

Comment: Hola Hans, te recomiendo que leas [ask] y completes el [tour] para conocer cómo se espera que se planteen las preguntas: Añade siempre el código como texto y usa las herramientas para darle el formato necesario. Las imágenes no permiten copiar y pegar a la respuesta el código, lo que suele ser el primer paso para dar una solución

Answer (score 0):

el like lo tienes mal implementado debes colorcalo asi `%:valor%`